# Big integer calculator c++

Tags: c++, arrays, bigint

So far I've got an add, subtract and print function as well as a constructor that initializes to zero the array. For some reason the operations(+ and -) made alot of sense to me(i think) so I kind of got ahead of my self and am not too sure how to initialize a big integer, could I get some help with a function such as 
void assign(const bigint & A) or something like that? Also if there is something already wrong with my code please tell me. Thanks

```
const int size=30;   //just to make things easier, will change to something big later
class bigint
{
    int digits[size];


public:
    // initializes to zero
    bigint()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            digits[i] = 0;

    }

    // prints a big int
    void print()
    {
        bigint B;
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int dig = B.digits[i];
            if (dig != 0)
                std::cout << dig;
        }
    }

    // subtracts a bigint(B) from another(A)
    void subtract(bigint & A, bigint & B)
    {
        for (int i = 0, borrow = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (borrow = ((A.digits[i] -= B.digits[i] + borrow) < 0))
            {
                A.digits[i] += 10;
            }
        }
    }

    // adds a bigint(A) to another(B)
    void add(bigint & A, bigint & B)
    {
        for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (carry = ((A.digits[i] += B.digits[i] + carry) < 9))
            {
                A.digits[i] -= 10;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: it's part of the assignment, we had to make a safe array class and use it for the calculator. My safearray works fine. I might have initialized it wrong in my bigint class if that's what you mean.

Comment: You shouldn't need an `assign` function. Unless you've messed up the copy semantics of `SafeArray`, the automatically-generated copy constructor and copy-assignment operator should do the right thing, copying all the data. (Although I'm a bit scared by the `[]` on the end of the `digits` declaration, and the separate `size` variable, implying that `SafeArray` is neither safe nor an array. But without knowing how that's meant to work, we can't say how it should be initialised or copied.)

Comment: also i don't like this 'clever code' inside of your add/substract methods. I guess it's kinda opinion based but for me readability comes first, and writing fewer lines of code comes at the very very last... Your if-statement contains (apart from checking a contition) also two assignments which is horrible from a readability point of view...

Comment: @jack Your `SafeArray` isn't an array.  If it was, why does it need the `[]`?  .  What you have declared is an arrray of `SafeArray`.  Second, you cnanot declare arrays in standard C++ using empty brackets.  So overall, your declaration should be just `SafeArray<int> digits;`   and all the management of an array should be internal within the SafeArray class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yeah i just caught that. I think I fixed it in the code using edit. I just made a regular array for now.

Comment: @jack You now have two `size` variables.  The only one that works for standard C++ when it comes to creating an array is the `const int` version.

Comment: I decided to set the size to an integer(30) for now. I'll change it later.

Comment: @jack You should write a constructor `bigint(int)` that takes an integer and copies the digits of the int to your `digit` array.  Otherwise your class is not going to be useful (or cannot be used easily).

Comment: @jack I think I get what you are trying to do here: you want to use the int digits[size] array to store your big integer. But you need to make sure your digits are actually digits and smth like digits[i]=100 is not allowed

Comment: @jack to initialize your big integer you probably have to parse a string and write a constructor for that; bigint myBigInt("1212323232323" );